# how to add an additional loop over a stringlist within a for_each

Tags: for-loop, github, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

i've setted up multiple github repos within my .tf configuration with a simple for_each on "github" repository resource. In addition i tried to create several branches (a branch per env) for each newly created repo.

My first intention was to use a module (./modules/github_repo/repo.tf) which includes

```
    locals {
      environments = var.environments
    }

    resource "github_branch" "branches" {
      for_each      = toset(setsubtract(local.environments, ["prod"]))
      repository    = "orgName/${var.REPO_NAME}"
      branch        = lookup(var.environment_to_branch_map, each.key, each.key)
      source_branch = "master" 
    }
```

with following variables

```
    variable "REPO_NAME" {
      type = string
    }
    
    variable "environments" {
      type    = list(string)
    }

    variable "environment_to_branch_map" {
      type = map(any)
      default = {
        "prod" = "master"
        "dev"  = "develop"
      }
```

calling like this from main.tf

```
    provider "github" {
      token = var.GITHUB_TOKEN
      owner = "orgName"
    }    

    locals {
      environments = ["dev", "prod", "staging", "test"]
      microServices  = tomap({ "service1" : "fnApp", "service2" : "fnApp" })
      default_branch = "master"
    }

    module "branches_per_microservice" {
      for_each     = local.microServices
      source       = "./modules/github_repo"
      REPO_NAME    = each.key
      environments = local.environments
      depends_on   = [github_repository.microservices]
    }
```

unfortunately i get an 404 for each branch and repo combination like this

> Error: Error querying GitHub branch reference /orgName/service1 (refs/heads/master): GET
> https://api.github.com/repos//orgName/service1/git/ref/heads/master: 404 Not Found []
> with
> module.branches_per_microservice["service1"].github_branch.branches["test"]
> on modules/github_repo/repo.tf line 23, in resource "github_branch" "branches":

i guess it's a "provider" thing, cause if i try to create a branch directly in the main.tf, it will work. but the problem is, that i only can use one loop within a resource. (i already know that providers are not possible in modules with count or for_each loops, as written in terraform docs)

```
resource "github_branch" "branches" {
  for_each      = toset(setsubtract(local.environments, ["prod"]))
  repository    = github_repository.microservices["service1"].name 
  branch        = lookup(var.environment_to_branch_map, each.key, each.key)
  source_branch = "master" 
}
```

in this case, i have to create a resource for each "MicroService" manually, which i want to avoid heavily... Are there any ideas how i could "nest" the second loop over the environments to create my branches for each Micorservice repos?

Many thx in advance for any hint, idea or approach here...

Answer (score 0):

Nested loop can be replaced with a single loop over the `setproduct` of two sets. The documentation for `setproduct` can be found here
https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setproduct

Comment: many thx @Fedor Petrov, but unfortunately thats not what i'm looking for. the cartesian product will create a repo for each possible combination. in my case i just want to have 1 to n repositories, and each of the repos should have a branch per provided "env" value. means if i have 2 repos (service 1, service 2) and 4 envs (prod, dev, staging, test) i would get 8 repositories, i just need 2 repositories (service 1 and service 2) and each should have the 4 env branches...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. If you have ["repo1", "repo2"] and ["prod", "dev", "staging", "test"].  You get cartesian product ["repo1", "prod"], ["repo1", "dev"], ["repo1", "staging"], ["repo1", "test"], ["repo2", "prod"], ["repo2", "dev"], ["repo2", "staging"], ["repo2", "test"]. If from each pair you use first element to name the repository and the second for the environment name, your resources will only reference "repo1" and "repo2" each with 4 envs. This results into 8 Terraform resources, but each resource is not a separate repo, but repo+env. or?

Comment: Anyway. If your code is in a "module" you can add for_each or count to the "module" itself to iterate over repositories. And another for_each inside of your module to iterate over environments.